# Python equivalent of Tcl "catch" with variable for error output

Tags: python

In Tcl, you can use the `catch` command to send error output to a variable, like this:

```
% catch {eval exec bogomips &} outage
1
% puts $outage
couldn't execute "bogomips": no such file or directory
```

In Python (at which I'm still a beginner), I know `try` is basically the equivalent of `catch`, but I'm not seeing how to capture error output in a variable. Can this be done in Python without resorting to subprocess, Popen, and so on? If so, how?

Comment: `try: do my stuff` `except MyException as e:` `pass`  Now `e` will be the exception.

Comment: Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: That got me an error message all right, but it wasn't captured in a variable called e.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I misunderstood.  You do need to use `subprocess` to do what you want.  If you want to do that, I can tell you how.

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to do that, but it's not as easy as using `catch` in Tcl. Fortunately, there is a way to evoke `catch` from Python if needed: after importing tkinter and messagebox, open a root window and run this line: `root.tk.eval('catch {eval exec bogomips &} outage; tk_messageBox -message $outage')` !

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day.  I didn't know that one could run Tcl commands in Python.

Comment: @zondo when you use TkInter you're not making direct calls to the Tk library (e.g., Perl interface to Tk directly calls the api) but you're talking via interprocess communication to a tcl interpreter linked with Tk.

Answer (score 0):

You use one or more `except` clauses, catching the appropriate exception types:

```
def something(x):
    if type(x) != int:
        raise TypeError("Expected an int, but was %s" % str(type(x)))
    if x == 0:
        raise ValueError("Zero not allowed")

try:
    something(0)
except ValueError as e:
    print 'got a value error:', e
except TypeError as e:
     print 'got a type error:', e
```

(Python 2 code, but Python 3 is the same in this regard.)

Here are the docs on Errors and Exceptions: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: You should use `if isinstance(x, int):` instead of `if type(x) == int:`  That way, subclasses of `int` will still qualify.  Also, use `if not x:` instead of `if x == 0:`  It's shorter.

Comment: Do what you will; it's just a suggestion.  I do have a fairly strong opinion on `isinstance()`, though.

Comment: Honest curiosity: why? Do people actually subclass int?

Comment: Actually, there's even a built-in that subclasses `int`: `bool`.

Comment: That gave me one of the specified error messages as expected, but that's not what I want. I want to capture the standard error output, e.g., `couldn't execute "bogomips": no such file or directory`. I looked at the docs and saw nothing (at least nothing obvious) about how to capture standard error output in a variable. I've used subprocess and Popen with success, but I'll be disappointed if Python doesn't offer a simpler way to do what you can to with one line of code in Tcl.

Comment: @McClamrock: SnildDolkow, Iropмудрий, and I all misunderstood your question.  You need to use `subprocess` to do what you want.

Comment: All right, then. Maybe some future version of Python will catch up with what Tcl could do in a single line of code long ago! :o(

Answer (score 0):

Catching error of external program:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.Popen("dir c:\\dosent\\exists", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).stderr.read().decode('cp866'))
```

Comment: I have discovered that he is talking of error messages from a separate program.  I would suggest that you delete this answer before someone comes here on a downvote spree.

Comment: This doesn't capture the error output in a variable either, as I found when I changed `print(err)` to `print('Bogosity: ' + err)`. I still got just the error message, no "Bogosity."

Comment: @McClamrock Perhaps this is what you want?